# I'm getting problems uploading images in django

Tags: python, django

This is the models.py file. Although you can see that i have used MEDIA_URL as the directory for the image to be saved, i have also messed around with all other alternatives getting similar error messages. Could this have something to do with permissions? im not sure.

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class  Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
body = models.TextField()
created = models.DateTimeField()
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = MEDIA_URL)



def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

This is the settings part i have added.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And this is the error message i am getting in the cmd(using windows)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 284, in execute
self.validate()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 310, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
self._populate()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 75, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 99, in load_app
models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Neema\sonder\blog\models.py", line 4, in <module>
class  Post(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\Neema\sonder\blog\models.py", line 8, in Post
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = MEDIA_URL)
NameError: name 'MEDIA_URL' is not defined
```

Comment: Check: `NameError: name 'MEDIA_URL' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a import to your `models.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

And then you can use it:

```
settings.MEDIA_URL
```

Anyway, I don't think it is a good practice to add the `MEDIA_URL` to your field. If in the future you decide to change it, you need to update all the DB entries.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mention MEDIA_URL in your models.py at all. Just mention a subdirectory name. For e.g.

```
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="blogimages")
```

Make sure that the media folder has write access by server (Apache or IIS). This is a common problem in Windows. It can be fixed easily by right clicking the folder and changing the permissions.

If you still get an error, please post that as well.

Comment: hey arun, would you mind if i could just send my whole project to you so you could have a look? no matter how hard i try i cant understand what the problem is. it could be something incredibly trivial because this is the first time i'm using django and python...

Comment: Ok, I can have a look. Mail me the code and the error you are currently facing. I can't guarantee to find the problem but I can try :)